# JPA @JoinColumns should still join rows when one column is null

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, join

I have 2 tables:

First one has id, column1, column2, column3. 
Second one has id, column1, column2, column4.

Respective entity for the first one:

```
@Entity
public class FirstEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "column1", referencedColumnName = "column1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column2", referencedColumnName = "column2")
    })
    private List<SecondEntity> secondEntity;

}
```

So join works fine with one exception: column2 may be null in both tables. And in that case rows with same column1 values where column2 is null should be joined as well.

With SQL I succeed in achieving this by updating join condition to

```
table1.column1 = table2.column1 and (coalesce(table1.column2, '') = coalesce(table2.column2, '')).
```

What can be done with Jpa (or Hibernate in particular) in order to get secondEntity field set for null column as well?

Comment: That's not possible. And I assume you also don't have a foreign key constraint on these two tables.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli table1 is actually a view, while columns 1 and 2 are foreign keys   of other 2 tables.